# How can I build a micro USB hub?

Tags: usb, diagram, usb-hub

**EDIT:** @EugeneSh.  I ment how can I build a hub
**Double edit:** Sorry everyone, I mentioned how can I build a USB hub...

I'm looking to build a very small USB Y splitter for my Nexus 7 2nd Gen so it has 2 USB ports.
The reason why I'm not buying one from eBay (ect.) is because i don't want a cord and I want to build something like the "sugoi hub" mentioned below.
I **WAS** going to buy a [sugoi hub](http://www.system-talks.co.jp/product/usb2/hub/microhub/usb2-hubmc2ss_nr.htm) but those things are nowhere to be found! 
Anyways, do any of you guys have an easy wiring diagram for a (micro) USB 2.0 Y splitter?

Comment: USB hub is an electronic device, not just a wiring box.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, I edited my answer

Comment: You start by googling 'USB hub controller IC' and from there probably following the 1st link to TI's site. You filter out all of the USB 3.0 devices (because even USB2.x 480Mbps is enough of a pain to design for). Then you look at other specs which are relevant to you and start reading datasheets. Alternatively you could replace the 1st step with a focused search on Digikey or whoever you favorite distributor is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these y splitters are, are a usb hub ic, a few passives, and the usb ports. It is an active device, not just wires. Some all in one USB hubs like GL850G are used. You could get a cheap dollar hub with one of those, then modify it as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't split the wires from a USB 2.0 port to make two or more ports.

A USB port can connect directly to (a) a USB hub i.e. an active electronic junction box or (b) a USB device, such as a printer or flash stick.

(There's a mountain of stuff underneath (b) to explain further but it won't help the point. Wikipedia's USB article will give you enough.)

Unless your USB socket carries more than one pair of USB connections, you need a USB hub to go from one USB port to two or more.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with this reference design, offered by one of manufacturers:

http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=EVB-USB2422

Then remove components that you don't need, replace Type-A connectors with micro-AB receptacles. One challenge will be to accommodate a micro-B plug, there is no connectors made for printed circuit board.

Then you can use any free design software (e.g. https://www.expresspcb.com/), and manufacture a mini-prototype, it is cheap, under $100 for a 4 layer board. Make sure your are using traces with 90-Ohm controlled differential impedance for USB D+/D- wires. Then you probably need to design a custom enclosure for your hub, by modifying some small plastic case. Or there are services that can do this for a couple of thousand bucks.

Good luck.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-Micro-USB-with-PCB-Board-Type-A-Male-Plug-Connector-Port-DIY-Parts-Plug/32822045045.html